# Java Script. Add new value to end of an array and shift the rest

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know what is the best way to add a new value to an end of an array and let the rest of values to shift with the first element of an array to be deleted.

Example. I got an array:

```
 int []a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

and after adding 7 i want to have this:

```
 int []a = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Comment: `int` in `javascript`, are you sure it's not `java`?

Comment: That's not JavaScript syntax.

Comment: This is perfect for a queue, might be worth looking into them! They're perfect for what you want! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: if an array js var s = [1,2,3,4,5,6] and then s,push(7) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] do a s.shift(); then s will be [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    var a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    console.log('a before:- ', a)
    a.push(7);
    var removed = a.shift(); // Save removed item if you need it
    
    console.log('a after:- ',a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice` method for remove element

```js
    var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    arr.push(7);
    arr.splice(0, 1);
    console.log(arr)
```

**Output**

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

for more information read this [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)